# Contiguous Block Plotting/Removal Logic

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, logic

I've been attempting to write some logic for a program I have been working on and have run into some difficulty.

Essentially what I'm creating on my stage programmatically is a 4x4 grid (16 blocks), which looks just like this:

[image: 4 x 4 grid]

The user's task is to plot a contiguous shape onto the grid by clicking on the blocks and their shape should feature **no gaps** and **no diagonally plotted blocks**, for example the following would be a legal shape:

[image: legal shape]

However, the following shape wouldn't be and would throw out an error to the user in the form of a pop-up graphic:

[image: illegal shape]

The plotting process for the grid is associated with a 4x4 virtual representation of the grid in Boolean Array form and looks like this:

```
    public static var ppnRowArray1:Array = [false,false,false,false];
    public static var ppnRowArray2:Array = [false,false,false,false];
    public static var ppnRowArray3:Array = [false,false,false,false];
    public static var ppnRowArray4:Array = [false,false,false,false];
    public static var ppnColumnArray:Array = [ppnRowArray1,ppnRowArray2,ppnRowArray3,ppnRowArray4];
```

As the user clicks and selects a block, changing the colour property to brown, the relevant boolean property in my 'virtual grid representation' array will change from false to true. If a plot is illegally made then this property is changed back to false and the user is then invited to try their next plot again.

I have managed to write the code which forces the user to plot a legal shape and works out when an illegal plot has been made, but I now need to write the logic for when a user de-selects a block from an existing legal shape, making it non-contiguous and this is where my problem lies.

Here is the working solution as it stands.

```
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static function ppnCountSetCells():int
    {
        //Count Each 4x4 Grid Cell
        var count:int = 0;
        for (var row=0; row<=3; row++)
        {
            for (var col=0; col<=3; col++)
            {
                if (ppnColumnArray[col][row])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static function ppnBlockValid():Boolean
    {
        if (ppnCountSetCells() > 1)
        {
            for (var row=0; row<=3; row++)
            {
                for (var col=0; col<=3; col++)
                {
                    if (ppnColumnArray[col][row] == true)
                    {
                        // Check if we are connected to another set square
                        var validNeighbours:int = 0;

                        // Check North
                        if (row > 0)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col][row - 1] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }

                        // Check South
                        if (row < 3)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col][row + 1] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }

                        // Check West
                        if (col > 0)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col - 1][row] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        // Check East
                        if (col < 3)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col + 1][row] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


                        if (validNeighbours < 1)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

function addBlock(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                //trace("You Have Clicked On Grid Block Number: " + e.currentTarget.id);

                if (InterfaceButtons.panelOpen == false)
                {
                    //Listen to see if the block click is adjoining and pass back to see if it is valid on the grid
                    var col:int = (e.currentTarget.id - 1) % 4;
                    var row:int = (e.currentTarget.id - 1) / 4;

                    ppnColumnArray[col][row] = true;

                    addOrRemove = "add";

                    ppnBlockValid();

                    //Get the Block Valid Result (True or False) and pass it into a Boolean variable to use later
                    ppnGridError = ppnBlockValid();


                    trace("Is This Valid? " + ppnBlockValid());

                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    //Push Blocks Selected into Array
                    ppnShapeArray[e.currentTarget.id] = true;
                    trace(ppnShapeArray);

                    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    //Add 1 to the block count which directly effects the final outcome depending on ++ or --
                    ppnBlocksSelected++;

                    PlantPopNitDesignPlot.ppnPlotMade = false;

                    //Hide Block to Reveal Brown One
                    e.currentTarget.alpha = 0;

                    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    //Output an error if one is present on Click based on gridError Boolean Variable
                    ppnOutputAddError();

                    if (ppnGridError == false)
                    {
                        //Restore the block's alpha property as it isn't allowed to be selected, removing counter by one -- and changing final output accordingly
                        e.currentTarget.alpha = 1;
                        ppnBlocksSelected--;
                        ppnColumnArray[col][row] = false;
                        ppnShapeArray[e.currentTarget.id] = false;
                        ppnPopulateTotalSiteUnitsTxt();
                    }

                    //Update final total
                    ppnPopulateTotalSiteUnitsTxt();

                    //Call again to do dynamic colour font change should total exceed 10
                    ppnPopulateTotalSiteUnitsTxt();

                    //Added in to make sure it executes every time if an error is made.
                    if (ppnGridError == true)
                    {
                        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBlock);
                        e.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeBlock);

                    }
                }

            }

            function removeBlock(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (InterfaceButtons.panelOpen == false)
                {

                    var col:int = (e.currentTarget.id - 1) % 4;
                    var row:int = (e.currentTarget.id - 1) / 4;

                    ppnColumnArray[col][row] = false;

                    addOrRemove = "remove";

                    ppnBlockValid();

                    ppnGridError = ppnBlockValid();

                    trace("Is This Removal Valid? " + ppnBlockValid());

                    //trace("You Have Clicked On Grid Block Number: " + e.currentTarget.id);

                    e.currentTarget.alpha = 1;

                    ppnShapeArray[e.currentTarget.id] = false;
                    //trace("ppnShapeArray - " + ppnShapeArray);

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

                    ppnBlocksSelected--;

                    PlantPopNitDesignPlot.ppnPlotMade = false;

                    //Output an error if one is present on Click based on gridError Boolean Variable
                    ppnOutputRemoveError();

                    if (ppnGridError == false)
                    {
                        //Restore the block's alpha property as it isn't allowed to be selected, removing counter by one -- and changing final output accordingly
                        e.currentTarget.alpha = 0;
                        ppnBlocksSelected--;
                        ppnColumnArray[col][row] = true;
                        ppnShapeArray[e.currentTarget.id] = true;
                        ppnPopulateTotalSiteUnitsTxt();

                    }

                    //Update Final Total
                    ppnPopulateTotalSiteUnitsTxt();

                    //Call again to do dynamic colour font change should total falls below 10
                    ppnPopulateTotalSiteUnitsTxt();

                    //Added in to make sure it executes every time.
                    if (ppnGridError == true)
                    {
                        e.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addBlock);
                        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeBlock);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, for most occurences this logic works and detects illegal plots when adding or removing a block to the shape, however recently I discovered that when I have 5 > blocks in the shape, the logic for detecting an error on removal fails in certain circumstances.

A few examples of shapes being declared true and legal when they are not (when a block has been removed) are as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can see that it is the logic written in my 'ppnBlockValid():Boolean' function that needs adjusting to compensate for these outputs. It seems you can only remove a block providing that the neighbouring blocks are still joined to something else. While this works for smaller shapes, larger shapes (e.g. 5 blocks or more) can theoretically be split down the middle, so I think the code needs adjusting to account for this.

But how? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance and if you need any further information from me please let me know.

Cheers,

Joel

---

**Edited**

Thank you very much for providing that enhanced code and explanation @dhc I really appreciate it, but I'm still a little confused about how to implement all this properly.

Here is my current 'ppnBlockValid' function code based on your suggestion below:

```
public static function ppnBlockValid():Boolean
    {
        ppnIslands = [];
        ppnAddNewIsland = [];
        ppnAddToExistingIsland = [];

        if (ppnCountSetCells() > 1)
        {
            for (var row=0; row<=3; row++)
            {
                for (var col=0; col<=3; col++)
                {
                    if (ppnColumnArray[col][row] == true)
                    {
                        var addedToIsland = false;

                        // Check if we are connected to another set square
                        var validNeighbours:int = 0;

                        // Check North
                        if (row > 0)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col][row - 1] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }

                            //----------------------------------

                            //ISLAND CHECK
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col][row - 1])
                            {
                                ppnAddToExistingIsland.push([col,row - 1],[col,row]);
                                addedToIsland = true;
                            }
                        }

                        // Check South
                        if (row < 3)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col][row + 1] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }

                        // Check West
                        if (col > 0)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col - 1][row] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }

                            //----------------------------------

                            //ISLAND CHECK
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col - 1][row])
                            {
                                ppnAddToExistingIsland.push([col - 1,row],[col,row]);
                                addedToIsland = true;
                            }
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        // Check East
                        if (col < 3)
                        {
                            if (ppnColumnArray[col + 1][row] == true)
                            {
                                validNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

                        if (! addedToIsland)
                        {
                            ppnIslands.push([col,row]);
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

                        if (ppnIslands.length >= 2 && addOrRemove == "remove")
                        {
                            trace("TWO ISLANDS HAVE BEEN FORMED AND AN ERROR SHOULD BE OUTPUT");
                            validNeighbours--;
                        }

                        /**/
                        //return (ppnIslands.length<=1);// 0 islands is valid also!

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

                        if (validNeighbours < 1)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been using the following shape as my experiment with the code:

[image]

Based on the above code and example shape, my current trace output is:

```
ppnIsland = |0,0|,0,2
ppnAddNewIsland = 
ppnAddToExistingIsland = 0,0, 1,0, 1,0, 2,0, 2,0, 3,0, 1,0, 1,1, 1,1, 1,2, 0,2, 1,2, 1,2, 2,2, 2,2, 3,2
```

It appears that despite the shape being contiguous, the code I've tried interpreting from you is finding an additional island, in this case 'Col: 0, Row: 2', before a block removal has even taken place? Is this right?

This code of course does output an error if I try to remove the middle (red) block as the 'ppnIsland' array contains > 1 island, however I don't think its detecting the correct output?

Do I need to cross-reference the 'ppnIsland' and 'ppnAddToExistingIsland' arrays using the indexOf command to check if either element is part of an existing island?

Joel

Comment: If your goal is to not create islands, a simple change to prevent block removal while polar adjacent blocks exist may not be sufficient.  Consider an 8-block circle: removing the north cell would not indicate creating two islands, since the south cell still connects the two.  Suppose the north row of the circle is represented as A-B-C, and you want to remove B, you'd likely need to traverse the adjacencies from cell A until you arrived at C.  Only then could you prove a valid block removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could track "islands" as separate lists as you process (in ppnBlockValid).  So, for instance (caps are selected tiles): 


```
a B c d
e F g H
i J k L
m n o p
```

When you process row one, you create an island for B.  When you process row 2, you find B connected to F, so the island becomes [B,F].  Then, when you encounter H, which is not connected, you have two islands: [B,F],[H].  On row 3, your islands would look like [B,F,J],[H,L].  If K were selected, you'd find J and L connected, and you'd consolidate them into one island.  You only have to check the current row for connections between islands, so you'd only have to check J and L in this case.

If you end up with one island, you're fine, otherwise not.  This is, unfortunately, an order n**2 search, but your grid is small so it probably doesn't mean much.

---

Something like this (WARNING: not debugged code):

```
private var islands : Array;

public function ppnBlockValid():Boolean {
    islands = [];
    if (ppnCountSetCells() > 1) {

        for (var row=0; row<=3; row++) {
            for (var col=0; col<=3; col++) {
                if (ppnColumnArray[col][row]) {
                    var addedToIsland = false;

                    // Check if we are connected to another set square

                    // Check North
                    if (row > 0) {
                        if (ppnColumnArray[col][row-1]) {
                            addToExistingIsland([col,row-1],[col,row]);
                            addedToIsland = true;
                        }
                    }

                    // Check South - not needed since next row will catch this on North

                    // Check West
                    if (col > 0) {
                        if (ppnColumnArray[col-1][row]) {
                            addToExistingIsland([col-1,row],[col,row]);
                            addedToIsland = true;
                        }
                    }

                    // Check East - not needed since next col will catch this on West

                    if (!addedToIsland) { addNewIsland([col,row]); }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return (islands.length<=1);    // 0 islands is valid also!
}
```

You just have to implement "addNewIsland" and "addToExistingIsland".  addNewIsland is easy: just add a new element to the islands array.  You may want to use a string ID for the tiles instead of an array (e.g. "01" instead of [0,1]) since it may make checking for existing elements easier (e.g. you can use indexOf to find a tile in an island).

addToExistingIsland is a bit trickier: you have to check if either element is part of an existing island, and consolidate those islands if so.  If not, the new tile just gets appended to the island.

---

You don't need to maintain 3 arrays, just one island array that, at the end of ppnBlockValid, will either be length > 1 (invalid), or less (valid).

You cannot just populate the "ppnAddNewIsland" and "ppnAddToExistingIsland" arrays-- these should be functions.  If ppnIslands is a class variable, then your addNewIsland function may look something like this:

```
private function addNewIsland(who) {
    ppnIslands.push([who]);
}
```

... the only optimization I'd probably make is to turn who (passed as an array [col,row]) into a character string, as I mentioned, to make finding whether a tile exists in an island easier.

Then, you need a function like:

```
private function addToExistingIsland( existing_island_tile, new_tile ) {
}
```

This function must:

- 1. check whether these two tiles already exist in the same island (just return if so)

  2. check whether new_tile is already on an island (consolidate the two islands into one if so)

  3. otherwise, just add new_tile to the island that existing_island_tile is a member of

The code I presented should work pretty much as-is-- although you could add back in the "validNeighbours" logic if you want a quick exit for isolated tiles.

Comment: This certainly sounds like the type of logic I need to implement into my project @dhc and builds on the good advice from Atriace. Regarding this 'island' search on a (grid) row basis, you mentioned writing this into my existing 'ppnBlockValid' Boolean function. Would this involve creating two new arrays, the first for the connecting blocks and the second for non-connecting blocks? How might this look in ActionScript3 within the 'ppnBlockValid' function?